# react - function inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen some of the example like

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = () : void => {
      console.log("getData")
    }
    getData()
  }, []);
```

But I can put the function outside `useEffect` with the same outcome.

```
  const getData = () : void => {
      console.log("getData")
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, []);
```

What is the difference between these 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that, if you declare the function outside the effect hook, every time the component re-renders, the function object will be created anew. In contrast, declaring the function inside means that that function only gets created when the hook runs. (The anonymous inline function passed to `useEffect` still gets created every render, though...) It's really not worth worrying about, but it's a difference.

The main reason some might prefer to declare the function inside the effect hook is to [constrain the scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/388055) as much as possible - if you do

```
const fn = () => ...

useEffect(fn, [])

// lots more code
```

Then, some readers of the code may (very reasonably) worry that `// lots more code` contains a reference to `fn`, which can't be determined without reading through all of `// lots more code`. Constraining your `getData` to only inside the effect hook makes the intent of the function easier to understand at a glance, especially in a big component.